# How can i check if the instance of that Object using call or apply method

Tags: javascript

```
function User(first, last){
  if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) )
    return new User(first, last);

  this.name = first + " " + last;
}

var name = "Resig";
var user = User("John", name);

assert( user, "This was defined correctly, even if it was by mistake." );
assert( name == "Resig", "The right name was maintained." );
```

To check whether the instance is created is using new operator, we do these in the constructor.

```
if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) )
```

OR

```
if ( !(this instanceof ___) )
```

OR

```
if ( !(this instanceof User) )
```

I have read in this forum that arguments.callee depreciated and we must use either apply or call method instead.

How can i check if the instance of that Object using call or apply method?

Comment: Can you clarify your last question? Doesn't seem like a complete coherent thought.

Comment: I was looking on different ways to check if the instance is of that type of Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last option you showed is the right way to see if the constructor was called with new. However, I don't personally like this process. It encourages developers to call constructors without the new operator.

Comment: I agree with it, can we check the same with call or apply method.

Comment: The call and apply methods provide a context under which the function will run under.  They basically do the same thing, just passing arguments differently.  I dont see how that is relevant.